# IGNITION SQL QUERY

Tags: sql, database, ignition

I am currently stuck with an SQL query in IGNITION DESIGNER.

I have a SQL table with some entries where the interesting part is built up as follows:

#### **TableXY**

| ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Objekt 1 | X | Order01 |
| Objekt 1 | X | Order01 |
| Objekt 1 | X | Order02 |
| Objekt 1 | Y | Order02 |
| Objekt 2 | X | Order03 |
| Objekt 2 | X | Order03 |
| Objekt 2 | X | Order04 |
| Objekt 2 | Y | Order04 |

I am searching within my table for all **ColumnC** that belong to **"Object 1"** and do not yet have a row with a **"Y"** in **ColumnB**.

As an output should thus appear:

| ColumnC |
| --- |
| Order01 |

My approach is as follows...

```
SELECT ColumnC FROM TableXY  WHERE ColumnA='Object 1' AND ColumnB = 'X'  IN ( SELECT FROM TableXY  WHERE ColumnA='Object 1' AND NOT ColumnB = 'Y' )
```

Do you have any idea what could be wrong?

Or how I could do it better?

Answer (score 0):

This query produces the expected result in my test database:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ColumnC 
FROM testdb.tablexy
WHERE ColumnA = 'Objekt 1'
    AND ColumnC NOT IN 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT `ColumnC`
        FROM testdb.tablexy
        WHERE ColumnA = 'Objekt 1'
            AND ColumnB = 'Y'
    );
```

It subqueries the unwanted result to make sure that none of the returned results are included in the subquery.

**Result:**

[image: Test database result]